# Rails v.2 custom map attribute to objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
#model
class Something 
 has_many :numbers
end

#controller
something = Something.all.first
numbers = Number.all
something.numbers = [numbers[0], numbers[4]] # can we do it like this?
puts "something = #{something.inspect}" => <#Something > // with no `numbers` we've set;
```

//the required "quality standarts" to post this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you save it first and then inspect.

If you don't want to persist it then you shouldn't use has_many

Just use a normal instance variable

```
class Something 
 attr_accessor :numbers
end
```

Comment: but i don't want to persist it. Just to have that property on object level.

Comment: Hm. What do you mean with "no result"?

Comment: something.numbers.length ; something.numbers[0].inspect

Comment: with nothing i meant: `something.inspect => <#Something >`, but i can see the proper result with `something.numbers`. Why? And is it possible to include `numbers` to `something.inspect` result?

Comment: Why it is so important that inspect shows the numbers? Inspect is mostly for debugging.

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu, because it shows the field that would be serialized in case: `obj.to_xml`. And i do need that `numbers` to be serialized as well

Comment: You have alternatives. You could override to_xml method. Also you could use some alternative to serialize the object, so you can have more control. I'm using https://github.com/nesquena/rabl for json (it renders xml too) and I like it. But you could use others. Or even pass a proc to the to_xml method, see how to do it at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu, can you, please, add your comment to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to **never** use `Something.all.first` and instead use `Something.first`. The former loads *every single* record in your table into memory, then takes the first, discarding the rest. The latter loads the first record. On large tables, this will cause very serious problems when your Rails process occupies several gigabytes of memory.

If you want to select multiple Number records, do it this way:

```
numbers = Number.find_all_by_id([ 0, 4 ])
numbers.each do |number|
  number.something = something
  number.save
end
```

The more advanced way to do this is:

```
Number.update_all({ :something_id => something.id }, { :id => [ 0, 4 ] })
```

Always look at the queries rendered in `log/development.log` to build an understanding of how ActiveRecord interprets your calls. The results can be surprising, especially to the uninitiated.

A `has_many` relationship implies that Number `belongs_to` Something. It also implies that Number has a `something_id` column that needs to be manipulated. You aren't doing any saving in your example to Number records, so they will probably not be associated correctly. I think Rails 3 handles this a lot better than Rails 2, behaving closer to what you're expecting.

Remember to *always* test your application against a non-trivial dataset. Generate sufficient amounts of fake test data to ensure that you handle pagination correctly and that mistakes like calling `all` are exposed very early in your development cycle.

The only occasion where using `all` is safe is if you are absolutely certain the number of items in the list is acceptably small. This is rarely the case for user supplied data. If a user *could* have a thousand items in a list, one of them probably will.

Comment: say i have 2 entities. "one" and "two". "One" has many "two"; What is the most efficient way to get all "one" with theirs "two" and serialize them to get something like [#<one twoes:[#<two>]>]? (with not more than 2 db requests)

Comment: You need to use the `:include` option to eager load the associations.

Comment: That will get `twoes` from DB but won't map them to `a` object, so that if we `a.to_xml` the result will be `#<one >` but not `#<one twoes:[#<two>]>`